# charts with same color per category

Tags: pandas, charts, colors

I have several charts (bar, pie). In every charts are the same categories (Bronx, Queens ...).
But in every chart the category (e.g. Bronx) is visualized in a different color. Does someone have an idea how to color a category in every chart in the same color ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn0yQ.png)

*my_c = ['green','blue','red','yellow','black']

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)
df.loc[:,'Stadtteil'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', ax = ax[0][0], colors = my_c)
ax[0][0].set(xlabel = 'Stadtteil', ylabel = 'Anzahl', title = 'Anzahl Bezirke pro Stadtteil')
ax[0][0].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelrotation = 45)

pd.crosstab(
    index = df.loc[:,'Stadtteil'], 
    columns = 'Einwohner',
    values = df.loc[:,'Einwohner'],  
    aggfunc='sum').plot(ax = ax[0][1], kind = 'pie', legend = False, y = 'Einwohner', colors = my_c)  
    
ax[0][1].set(ylabel = '')

df.groupby('Stadtteil')['Einwohner'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind = 'bar', ax = ax[1][1], colors = my_c)
ax[1][1].set(xlabel = 'Stadtteil', ylabel = 'Anzahl Einwohner', title = 'Anzahl Einwohner pro Stadtteil')
ax[1][1].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelrotation = 45)   

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()*
```

I tried to use a dictionary to map the colors to the categories but this didnt work. Also teh use of a colormap didnt was succesful.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is associate a color to each category. You can either do this manually like this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Stadtteil': ['Bronx', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island', 'Bronx', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island'],
    'Einwohner': [100, 200, 150, 250, 50, 120, 220, 180, 270, 60]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

category_colors = {
    'Bronx': 'green',
    'Queens': 'blue',
    'Brooklyn': 'red',
    'Manhattan': 'yellow',
    'Staten Island': 'black'
}

df['color'] = df['Stadtteil'].map(category_colors)
```

or dynamilcally if you have a large number of categories:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Stadtteil': ['Bronx', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island', 'Bronx', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island'],
    'Einwohner': [100, 200, 150, 250, 50, 120, 220, 180, 270, 60]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

unique_stadtteils = df['Stadtteil'].unique()
n_categories = len(unique_stadtteils)

colormap = plt.cm.get_cmap('tab20', n_categories)  
category_colors = {stadtteil: colormap(i) for i, stadtteil in enumerate(unique_stadtteils)}
```

Then, doing exactly what you did (with adding the referense to the dictionary)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 8))

stadtteil_counts = df['Stadtteil'].value_counts()
colors = [category_colors[stadtteil] for stadtteil in stadtteil_counts.index]
stadtteil_counts.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[0][0], color=colors)
ax[0][0].set(xlabel='Stadtteil', ylabel='Anzahl', title='Anzahl Bezirke pro Stadtteil')
ax[0][0].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelrotation=45)

stadtteil_population = df.groupby('Stadtteil')['Einwohner'].sum()
colors = [category_colors[stadtteil] for stadtteil in stadtteil_population.index]
stadtteil_population.plot(ax=ax[0][1], kind='pie', legend=False, colors=colors)
ax[0][1].set(ylabel='')

colors = [category_colors[stadtteil] for stadtteil in stadtteil_population.sort_values(ascending=False).index]
stadtteil_population.sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1][1], color=colors)
ax[1][1].set(xlabel='Stadtteil', ylabel='Anzahl Einwohner', title='Anzahl Einwohner pro Stadtteil')
ax[1][1].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelrotation=45)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

produces

[image]

Add other plots the same way.